# Preload trying to get the wrong column name

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following objects.

```
defmodule Ketchup.Review do
  ...

  schema "order_review" do
    ...

    has_many :review_tags, Review.Tag

  end
end
```

And

```
defmodule Ketchup.Review.Tag do
  ...
  schema "review_tag" do
    ...
    belongs_to :order_review, Ketchup.Review
  end
end
```

And using the following query

```
@preload [:review_tags, :order]
def get_review_by_order(order_id) do
  Ketchup.Review
  |> where([c], c.order_id == ^order_id)
  |> preload(^@preload)
  |> Repo.one()
end
```

Give the following error:

```
 ** (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:495: field `Ketchup.Review.Tag.review_id` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query:

 from t in Ketchup.Review.Tag,
   where: t.review_id == ^2,
   order_by: [asc: t.review_id],
   select: {t.review_id, t}
```

Where is coming this `review_id` ? I've checked all the code for review and any atom or association, but can't find anything. It should be `order_review_id`.

The review tag is created with the following migration:

```
create table(:review_tag) do
  add :review_tag, :string
  add :order_review_id, references(:order_review, on_delete: :delete_all)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ecto is trying to use the key `review_id` because your module name ends with `Review`. If you want to use some other key, you will have to specify the `:foreign_key` option in your [`has_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3) call.

```
has_many :review_tags, Ketchup.Review, foreign_key: :order_review_id
```

Just note that I am guessing the key name based on the `belongs_to/3` you have specified.

Comment: The correct code is: 

    has_many :review_tags, Ketchup.Review.Tag, foreign_key: :order_review_id

But still, shouldn't Ecto be looking into the schema name, in this case `order_review` add add the `_id` after ?

Comment: I've changed Ketchup.Review to Ketchup.Order.Review to be more in context, but if I have Ketchup.Food.Review I need keep changing the foreign_key to point into the right direction and that is a bit confusing.

Comment: It could honestly work both ways. If it worked on the schema name as you proposed, I could see people asking the opposite question here. :) One advantage I can think of keeping the way things are though is that it relies on Elixir code conventions rather than the database ones, which can wildly vary.